# BBC radiation: What is it?

Tags: astronomy, soft-question, astrophysics, scattering

I'm reading articles about blazars, and in a discussion about models concerning Blazar SEDs (Spectral Energy Densities) there are mentions of different processes: Sychrotron scattering, inverse Compton scattering, etc.

Now concerning models for blazar emission, there are a lot of acronyms. I managed to figure out that SSC stands for "Self Synchrotron-Compton," but I have no idea what the acronyms "XC" and "BBC" stand for. And it isn't easy to google out "bbc + anything" without finding just references to... you know: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBC

Does anyone know or have a good sense of what those acronyms might stand for?

Comment: Can you provide a link or links to examples of these acronyms

Comment: It's actually [Synchrotron Self-Compton](http://www.cv.nrao.edu/course/astr534/InverseCompton.html), not Self Synchrotron-Compton.

Comment: XC might be an acronym for "external Compton" but I'm *reasonably* certain that BBC means "Blackbody Compton."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSC: synchrotron self-Compton

BBC: Compton upscattered blackbody radiation; Compton upscattering of stellar blackbody
photons

XC: upscattering of photons emitted by the accretion flow; accretion flow photons

From: http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.1309 and http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.4768

Comment: I'm not sure where 'XC' comes from. I merely suspect it is not an acronym, but rather derived from $x_\text{c}$, the sonic (or critical) point distance. I may be wrong about that.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files, e.g., http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.1309 and http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.4768